How to update array of recursive elements swift?
I am trying to make a simple file tree in SwiftUI however I have found an issue for which my coding skills aren't good enough. Basically the tree consists of a view called 'FileView', which is called recursively and contains a disclosuregroup, for folders. However when I delete a file, it gets deleted, but the view doesn't update. I can't just call the loading function again, because that would reset the state of all discloregroups, and I would have to reopen every single one. What I also can't do, is for example a file gets deleted by another application, or the user does it outside of the app. then the app should detect that, and also update itself.
The app also doesnt require sandbox.
If you have any questions about my code, please just write a comment and i'll try to answer it as best as I can.
Help is greatly appreciated.
Here is my code, which should be ready to run, however in order to work you have to disable sandbox.
import SwiftUI

struct FileModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var parentDirectory: URL?
    var fileURL: URL
    var subFiles: [FileModel]?
    
    var systemImage: String {
        if let subFiles {
            if fileURL.pathExtension == "app" {
                return "app.badge.fill"
            }
            if subFiles.isEmpty {
                return "folder"
            } else {
                return "folder.fill"
            }
        } else {
            switch fileURL.pathExtension {
            case "app": return "app.fill"
            case "png", "jpg", "tiff": return "photo.fill"
            case "pdf": return "doc.richtext"
            case "csv", "json": return "list.bullet.indent"
            case "bom": return "doc.richtext"
            case "stl", "obj", "usdz": return "cube.transparent.fill"
            case "mp3", "wav": return "waveform"
            default: return "doc.fill"
            }
        }
    }
}

func deleteFile(url: URL) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

struct FileView: View {
    @State var file: FileModel
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let subFiles = file.subFiles {
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    ForEach(subFiles) { subFile in
                        FileView(file: subFile)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label(file.fileURL.lastPathComponent, systemImage: file.systemImage)
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: file.systemImage)
                    Text(file.fileURL.lastPathComponent)
                }
            }
        } .tag(file.fileURL)
            .contextMenu {
                Button("Show in finder") {
                    NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([file.fileURL])
                }
                Button("Open with external editor") {
                    NSWorkspace.shared.open(file.fileURL)
                }
                Button("Delete") {
                    deleteFile(url: file.fileURL)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var rootFiles: [FileModel] = []
    @State private var selection: Set<URL>?
    
    @State private var showPicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(rootFiles) { file in
                    FileView(file: file)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("Load Directory") {
                        showPicker.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $showPicker, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], onCompletion: { result in
            do {
                let url = try result.get()
                Task {
                    rootFiles = await loadDirectory(url: url)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
}

func loadDirectory(url: URL) async -> [FileModel] {
    var fileModels = [FileModel]()
    
    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
        
        await withTaskGroup(of: FileModel?.self) { group in
            for content in contents {
                group.addTask {
                    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
                    let localFileManager = FileManager() // Create a new FileManager instance
                    localFileManager.fileExists(atPath: content.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
                    
                    if isDirectory.boolValue {
                        // Recursively load subdirectory
                        let subFiles = await loadDirectory(url: content)
                        return FileModel(parentDirectory: url, fileURL: content, subFiles: subFiles)
                    } else {
                        // It's a file
                        return FileModel(parentDirectory: url, fileURL: content, subFiles: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            for await fileModel in group {
                if let fileModel = fileModel {
                    fileModels.append(fileModel)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error loading directory: \(error)")
    }
    
    return fileModels
}


You're deleteFile(url: URL) function removes them from the FileManager but that has no effect on the arrays of files since you never refetch/validate from the FileManager. You'll need to update the stored arrays to see any change in the UI, either by recalling loadDirectory() or manually updating the State arrays (or using observation and sideeffects to do both)

Yes I know that, but doing so would reset all of the discloregroups expand state to false

Did you try a Bibding in FileView to reflect the change in parent view. Or may be use a observable FileViewModel with a published file model.

good, idea. could you write that?

Here with Binding (may not be the better solution but works).
Important note : it is the parent directory of a file which must remove it from its children.
struct FileModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var parentDirectory: URL?
    var fileURL: URL
    var isDirectory: Bool // define if directory or not
    var subFiles: [FileModel] = [] // empty for directiry
    
    var systemImage: String {
        if isDirectory {
            if fileURL.pathExtension == "app" {
                return "app.badge.fill"
            }
            if subFiles.isEmpty {
                return "folder"
            } else {
                return "folder.fill"
            }
        } else {
            switch fileURL.pathExtension {
                case "app": return "app.fill"
                case "png", "jpg", "tiff": return "photo.fill"
                case "pdf": return "doc.richtext"
                case "csv", "json": return "list.bullet.indent"
                case "bom": return "doc.richtext"
                case "stl", "obj", "usdz": return "cube.transparent.fill"
                case "mp3", "wav": return "waveform"
                default: return "doc.fill"
            }
        }
    }
    
    // delete a subfile from the list
    mutating func delete(subFile: FileModel) {
        guard let index = subFiles.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == subFile.id}) else { return }
        subFiles.remove(at: index)
    }
}

func deleteFile(url: URL) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

struct FileView: View {
    @Binding var file: FileModel // Use a binding to have UI synchronization
    
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    let deleteFileCallBack: (FileModel) -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if file.isDirectory { // use isDirectiry property
                DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                    ForEach($file.subFiles) { $subFile in // note the syntax for binding property
                        FileView(file: $subFile, deleteFileCallBack: self.delete(subFile:))
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label(file.fileURL.lastPathComponent, systemImage: file.systemImage)
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: file.systemImage)
                    Text(file.fileURL.lastPathComponent)
                }
                .contextMenu { // context menu is associated to the file
                    Button("Show in finder") {
                        NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting([file.fileURL])
                    }
                    Button("Open with external editor") {
                        NSWorkspace.shared.open(file.fileURL)
                    }
                    Button("Delete") {
                        deleteFile(url: file.fileURL)
                        self.deleteFileCallBack(file) // tell the caller to remove the file from the list
                    }
                }
            }
        } .tag(file.fileURL)
    }
    
    func delete(subFile: FileModel) { // this will be used by subview to indicate a subfile must has been deleted
        guard let index = file.subFiles.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == subFile.id}) else { return }
        file.subFiles.remove(at: index)
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State
    private var rootFiles: [FileModel] = []
    
    @State
    private var selection: Set<URL>?
    
    @State private var showPicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach($rootFiles) { $file in // Binding loop
                    FileView(file: $file, deleteFileCallBack: self.delete(rootFile:))
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Button("Load Directory") {
                        showPicker.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $showPicker, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], onCompletion: { result in
            do {
                let url = try result.get()
                Task {
                    rootFiles = await loadDirectory(url: url)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
    
    // to tell the subview how to delete the file
    func delete(rootFile: FileModel) {
        guard let index = rootFiles.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == rootFile.id}) else { return }
        rootFiles.remove(at: index)
    }
}

func loadDirectory(url: URL) async -> [FileModel] {
    var fileModels = [FileModel]()
    
    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles])
        
        await withTaskGroup(of: FileModel?.self) { group in
            for content in contents {
                group.addTask {
                    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
                    let localFileManager = FileManager() // Create a new FileManager instance
                    localFileManager.fileExists(atPath: content.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
                    
                    if isDirectory.boolValue {
                        // Recursively load subdirectory
                        let subFiles = await loadDirectory(url: content)
                        return FileModel(parentDirectory: url, fileURL: content, isDirectory: true, subFiles: subFiles)
                    } else {
                        // It's a file
                        return FileModel(parentDirectory: url, fileURL: content, isDirectory: false) // no subfiles because directory
                    }
                }
            }
            
            for await fileModel in group {
                if let fileModel = fileModel {
                    fileModels.append(fileModel)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error loading directory: \(error)")
    }
    
    return fileModels
}

